# Average of 10 numbers - Arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to find the avg of 10 numbers using an Array in C, however, while executing the code, I am able to input only one element.
Here's the code for ref. -

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int grade[10] ;
 int count = 10;
 long sum = 0;
 float average = 0.0f;

 printf("Enter 10 grades: \n");

 int i;
 for (i = 0; i<count; ++i);
 {
   printf("%2u> ", i+1);
   scanf("%d",&grade[i]);
   sum += grade[i];
 }
 average = (float)(sum/count);

 printf("\n Average: %.2f",average);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, change `(float)(sum/count)` to `(float)sum/count`. To convert sum to float before division. Otherwise, the program first performs an integer division and only then converts to float.

Comment: As pointed out above, you're doing integer division when you want floating point division (otherwise why use a `float` for the result?)  So all you're doing is computing an integer average, then converting that integer to `float` for no reason before printing it.

Comment: OT: There is no reason to use an array for this.. `int grade[10] ;`-> `int grade;` and `scanf("%d",&grade[i]);`--> `scanf("%d",&grade[);` and `sum += grade[i];` --> `sum += grade;`

Comment: @TomKarzes So you are suggesting I should directly take a `float` as input?

Comment: @SouvikDatta Look at the first comment posted by Gassa.  Were you not able to understand it?  Now, you *could* change the inputs to `float` if you don't want to restrict them to integers.  But the main point is that if you divide one integer type by another integer type, the result will have an integer type.  Do you know what `1/2` is in C?  It's `0`.  Try it.  But `1.0 / 2` will do the division in floating point, and the result will be `0.5`.

Comment: @SouvikDatta It will be a different program if you change input from integer to float. Only your requirement specification can tell what is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
for (i = 0; i<count; ++i);
```

Remove that trailing semicolon and it works as expected. As programmed, the semicolon is a statement, which constitutes the loop body. As if you had written this:

```
for (i = 0; i<count; ++i)
  {
  ;
  }
```

Comment: That's one of the errors.  It's not the only one.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Oh yes, you're right. `average = (float)(sum/count);` is another one. Are there more?